# Unable to authenticate using MEWS on FBA site programatically

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, development, forms-authentication, access-denied

I am trying to authenticate on my FBA site (*On-Prem SP2013*) using **Content Matrix Extensions Web Service**. However, I am getting the below error -

> MEWS Url:
>   http://myserver:9090/sites/fbasite/_vti_bin/ml/8.5.0.2/mlspextensions.asmx.
>   Exception: Server was unable to process request. ---> Access is
>   denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)) --->
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to
>   process request. ---> Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

I am able to successfully authenticate with **Native Web Service** url - 
http://myserver:9090/sites/fbasite/_vti_bin/authentication.asmx
using [**this**](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/17349/69297) approach.

However, I can see that '**/authentication.asmx**' does not exist for '**/ml/8.5.0.2/**' and I also do not see any corresponding Auth or Login method in '**/mlspextensions.asmx**'

> [**Note:** My FBA site is also having Windows auth enabled.]

Can someone please help with this authentication issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding the authenticated cookies to my MEWS object as well. This was a miss from my side.

So as a thumb rule, in case of **[FBA sites + (NWS or MEWS)]** the authenticated cookies have to be added.

```
    // Sample code snippet
this.websService = new Webs();  // This is a web service
this.websService.Url = siteUrl + "/_vti_bin/Webs.asmx";
this.websService.Credentials = credentials;
this.mewsService = new MLSPExtensionsWebService();  // This is a web service
this.mewsService.Url = siteUrl + "/_vti_bin/ml/" + mewsVersion + "/mlspextensions.asmx";
this.mewsService.Credentials = credentials;
    // Besides URL and credentials there are other initializations as well.
if (cookie != null)
{
    this.websService.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    this.websService.CookieContainer.Add(cookie);

    this.mewsService.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
    this.mewsService.CookieContainer.Add(cookie);   // This I missed.
}
```